# Can't add repository to install from on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS when switching from Python 3.8 to 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install an application and as mentioned in the manual, I am trying to add it's repository without luck:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I have tried to reinstall using this solution:

```
sudo apt remove python3-apt
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install python3-apt
```

Still get the same error on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Python version is: 3.7.9

I must say that it work when I switch to python 3.8 using `update-alternatives`.
Maybe this can help you to guide me what should I change.

Comment: Packages you install with `pip` are only available to the version of Python you installed them under. There is no mystery here.

Comment: @tripleee I am sorry but here I'm trying to add repository, please advise what should I change/add/install in order to make it work with Python 3.7.9 also.
I would like to understand what is missing and avoid it in the future.

Comment: You should not fiddle with the system python, as you see some important packages (like apt) depend on it. You can always have local python installations in your own user home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the repository manually (working around the `add-apt-repository` script problem):

Import the gpg key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com EA8CACC073C3DB2A
```

Add the ppa:

```
printf "%s\n" "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal main" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-shutter-focal.list
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

[Technical details: Linux Uprising team (check the gpg key)](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Answer (score 0):

In order to install shutter in ubuntu-20 just do:

```
sudo snap install shutter
```

It installs all packages needed in box without interferences with other software.